# Streamlit Cloud OSError: [E053] Could not read config file

Tags: spacy, streamlit

I am deploying an app that specifically requires `spaCy==3.3.1` to Streamlit cloud, which I added to the `requirement.txt` as well as the link to download and install `en_core_web_sm` which is

`https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm`.

The import is okay but when I load the model i.e. `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`, I will get the `OSError` below:

`OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from /home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/config.cfg`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

My `requirements.txt`:

```
spacy==3.3.1

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm
```

Main code:

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

I expected no error but got the `OSError: [E053]` above.

Comment: J Ferrarons is correct, but just to be 100% clear, v2 models won't work with v3.

Answer (score 2):

> Packages trained with spaCy v2.x are not compatible with spaCy v3.x
> ([source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7403))

Note that the model has version 2.2.0 but spacy has version 3.3.1.

I'd suggest to use a newer version of the model. The requirements could look like:

```
spacy==3.3.1
en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.3.0/en_core_web_sm-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
```